# Can Windows 10 be installed on a Lenovo Chromebook ThinkPad x131e?

Tags: windows-10

I am currently thinking about moving from Chrome OS to Windows 10.

Has anyone ever tried to install Windows 10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad X131e? Are there drivers available? I've looked for drivers on the Lenovo site but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it appears the Thinkpad X131e can run Windows 10. There is a compatibility list [here on the Lenovo site](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x131e/solutions/HT103535#thinkpad) and there are other resources you can find by Googling "Lenovo Thinkpad X131e windows compatible". Based on older posts it looks like there isn't always immediate support for the newest/largest Windows patches and/or general updates, so keep that in mind - Windows 10 will always want to update automatically.

Comment: I'm trying to install Windows 10 but Pen drive is not detecting, Do you know that how to boot from USB in Chromebook?

Comment: make sure booting from USB is enabled in your BIOS, then while you're booting you press whatever key is tied to your boot menu to select your USB drive. there are some instructions here: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht118361